# create dynamic xml sitemapl with php

Tags: php, xml

I have error:

This page contains the following errors:
error on line 4 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of
the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

```
<?php include 'config.php';
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "utf-8"?>';
echo '<urlset
xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
xmlns:xsi="http//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">';
echo '<url>
    <loc>http://cebhe.info/</loc>
     <changefreq>always</changefreq>
    </url>';
$get_menus_sql = $db->prepare("SELECT id,ad FROM kateqoriyalar");
$get_menus->execute();
foreach($get_menus_sql as $get_menus){
$menu_name = $get_menus['id'];
$menu_slug = $get_menus['ad'];
if($pagename == $menu_slug)
{$menuselected = 'select';}else{$menuselected = '';}
echo'
    <url>
    <loc>http://cebhe.info/kat.php?'.$menu_name.'</loc>
      <changefreq>always</changefreq>
    </url>'; }
$sitemap=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM yazilar ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
$sitemap->execute();
foreach($sitemap as $sm){
echo'
    <url>
        <loc>http://cebhe.info/'.seolink(strip_tags($sm['basliq'])).'-'.$sm['id'].'</loc>
        <changefreq>always</changefreq> 
    </url>    
    ';}
echo '</urlset>';?>
```

Comment: is there any output produced in config.php? What does the rendered output look like?

Comment: config.php

<?php


try { 

$db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cebhe_son",'cebhe_son','19Hemidirasim94');
$db->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'; SET CHARSET 'utf8'");

echo " ";

 } 

catch (Exception $e) {

 echo $e->getMessage();
 
}


?>

Comment: It's very likely that file config.php has some extra characters after php-tag ```?>```, so delete them. Or, the best, remove php-tag ```?>```

Comment: and remove string with ```echo " "; ```